# Get foursquare place details with/without API

Tags: facebook, foursquare

I want to know the best way how to obtain the basic info of a foursquare location, so for instance the mayor, total checkins, profile picture,...

Important: I should be able to get this information without providing an oauth_token, and that exactly is my problem. The API demands a token, but I figured it should be possible to get the data without the token, because you can access places without authenticating.
E.g.: https://foursquare.com/v/whole-foods/49bc3b0af964a52020541fe3

The reason I want to do this, is because I want to make a facebook application which fetches the data for a locationbased facebook page and I don't want to demand the facebook users to login to foursquare first.

An alternative is webscraping, but that really is my last option.

Thanks in advance for your responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "[Venues Platform](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/venues)" allows you to access venue information through the API without an OAuth token. You can access all the information you're looking for, all you need to do is supply your Client ID and Client Secret when making a request to the `/venues` API endpoint.